# How to give the access to show all calendar events in admin user side in salesforce?

Tags: user, event, calendar, sharing-rule, user-admin

I created calendar event through admin side, It will be showing standard calendar events. Now I created another event through User A, He is standard user profile. But my doubt is User A already created one calendar event, It can't showing Admin side. Why? Administrator have all permissions access to view the all users events. I give sharing access of calendar 'Show Details and Add Events' in Organization Wide Default. Why it can't access to admin user? Could anybody please help on this.

### see below images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What view do you use to see a calendar? Make sure you use the [Multi User View](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activities_using_calendar_icons_cex.htm&type=5) on the Calendar.

Comment: Yes Eduard, I want to use Multi User View

Comment: So do you see all the events now?

Comment: @Eduard, When User A created one calendar event, it will be display only User A but not Showing that event in Admin view. Why? Admin have all access to view all events of any user? please tell me

Comment: Please attach screenshots for all your cases (when user A is logged in, and when admin is logged in). Without these details it's hard to tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Eduard, Now I attached Screenshots, Could you please check once and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you **[need to change](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activities_using_calendar_icons_cex.htm&type=5)** the calendar to the user's calendar you want to see:

> Click Change to switch users or calendars.

By default your admin user sees his own calendar in a Single-User View. So you need you switch it to be able to see other's user calendar in a Single-User View.

[image]